# How to make similar objects have similar embedding weights?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In the read world, there are many many phones(aa ae ah ao ar aw ax ay b ch d dh ...).

But for brief,I only use three phones(**aa ah ae**) to illustrate my question.And it ***only need training Data,no Test Data*** in all process.

There are two file, one is [**train_forWolfram.dat(928 KB)**](https://wolfr.am/m6DMp7U1), the other is [**phone_id.csv(2 KB)**](https://wolfr.am/m6DNA4FN).All data are rea-world data,but already normalization.

Importing training file and define the net:

*`EmbeddingLayerInput` is phone ID.`INPUT2` is frame information, and the `output` is audio information in current frame.*

```
data = Partition[BinaryReadList["https://wolfr.am/m6DMp7U1", "Real32"], {1 + 12 + 43}];

generator = Function[<|"EmbeddingLayerInput" -> Rationalize@#[[All, 1]], "Input2" -> #[[All, 2 ;; 13]], "Output" -> #[[All, 14 ;;]]|> &@RandomSample[data, #BatchSize]];

INPUTNOTE = Max[data[[All, 1]]];
net = NetGraph[{EmbeddingLayer[32, "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", Range[0, INPUTNOTE]}]], CatenateLayer[], 64, Ramp, 64, Ramp, 43}, 
     {NetPort["EmbeddingLayerInput"] -> 1 -> 2, NetPort["Input2"] -> 2, 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7}, 
     "Input2" -> 12]
```

Then train the net(batch size:64 examples, epochs:100 rounds):

```
{net, LossEvolutionPlot} = NetTrain[net, generator, 
   MeanSquaredLossLayer[], {"TrainedNet", "LossEvolutionPlot"}, 
   BatchSize -> 64, MaxTrainingRounds -> Round[Length[data]/64*100]];
```

[image]

View `data[[All,1]]`:
The adjacent same number means it's the same phone but in different frame.

[image]

Also view [phone_id.csv(2 KB)](https://wolfr.am/m6DNA4FN):

The First row is phone_ID, the second row is phone name.

[image]

View the embedding matrix,and try to find whether the same phone has smallest distance.

```
embeddingWeights = NetExtract[net[[1]], "Weights"];
phoneid = Import["https://wolfr.am/m6DNA4FN", "Table"];
nearstData = Nearest[embeddingWeights, DistanceFunction ->EuclideanDistance];
Assodata = Association@Thread[embeddingWeights ->Range[Length@embeddingWeights]]; 
ReplaceiablePhone = Table[phoneid[[x]] -> phoneid[[Assodata[nearstData[embeddingWeights[[phoneid[[x, 1]] + 1]], 2][[2]]]]], {x, Length@phoneid}];

MinMax@data[[All, 1]] == MinMax@phoneid[[All, 1]](*True*)
```

`ReplaceiablePhone` got these.

*It means the phone of ID 0 is much like the phone of ID 110.(correctly),the phone of ID 1 is much like the phone of ID 88.(correctly)...*

[image]

Then use `MatrixPlot` to plot these relationships：

```
confusionMatrixData = #[[1, 2]] -> #[[2, 2]] & /@ ReplaceiablePhone;
phone = Union@confusionMatrixData[[All, 1]];
m = Normal@SparseArray@Normal@Counts[{#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ (confusionMatrixData /. Thread[phone -> Range[Length@phone]])];
t = Transpose@Map[Flatten, {#, Reverse@Transpose@#} &[Table[Range[1, 2 # - 1, 2], {#}]] &[Length@m]]/2;
p = MatrixPlot[m, Epilog -> Text @@@ Transpose[{Catenate@m, t}], FrameTicks -> {Transpose@{Range[Length@phone], phone}, Transpose@{Range[Length@phone], Total[m, {1}]}, Transpose@{Range[Length@phone], Total[m, {2}]},Transpose@{Range[Length@phone], phone}}, ImageSize -> 150];
Column[{Row[{Rotate["phone", 90 Degree], p}, Alignment -> Center], "Nearest phone"}, 
        Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

the `ConfusionMatrixPlot` of **full phone** in [here](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xiaozh/SE/ConfusionMatrixPlot_32_1024_epochs50.pdf)

You can see the diagonal of matrix is really bigger than other, and the net really learn something.But it still have misclassified data.

Using *TSNE* to reduce dimension,we can plot it.

```
features = DimensionReduce[embeddingWeights, 2, Method -> "TSNE"];
classify = GroupBy[Thread[features -> phoneid[[All, 2]]], Last -> First]; 
ListPlot[Values[classify], PlotLegends -> PointLegend[97, Keys@classify, 
         LegendMarkerSize -> 15]]
```

[image]

You can see it has effect in some way ,but could we make it more separable for different phone and more compact for same phone?

The low dimension visualization of **full phone** is:

[image]

If the net has good ability,it will have smallest number of misclassified examples in Confusion Matrix, and the clusters will be more clear,just like this:

[image]

So how to make similar objects have similar embedding weights?

Can `NetPairEmbeddingOperator` help?

Comment: hi, dear partida, I happen to see your post, do you have the full labels of your full data?

Comment: @HyperGroups what kind of data? for visualize embedding space or confusion matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a nice way can deal with it.

First thing is the same as before:

```
data = Partition[BinaryReadList["https://wolfr.am/m6DMp7U1", "Real32"], {1 + 12 + 43}];

generator = Function[<|"EmbeddingLayerInput" -> Rationalize@#[[All, 1]],"Input2" -> #[[All, 2 ;; 13]], "Output" -> #[[All, 14 ;;]]|> &@RandomSample[data, #BatchSize]];

INPUTNOTE = Max[data[[All, 1]]];
net = NetGraph[{EmbeddingLayer[32, "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", Range[0, INPUTNOTE]}]], CatenateLayer[], 64, Ramp, 64, Ramp, 43},{NetPort["EmbeddingLayerInput"] -> 1 -> 2, NetPort["Input2"] -> 2, 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7}, "Input2" -> 12]

{net, LossEvolutionPlot} = NetTrain[net, generator, MeanSquaredLossLayer[], {"TrainedNet", "LossEvolutionPlot"}, BatchSize -> 64, MaxTrainingRounds -> Round[Length[data]/64*100]];

embeddingWeights = NetExtract[net[[1]], "Weights"];
phoneid = Import["https://wolfr.am/m6DNA4FN", "Table"];
nearstData = Nearest[embeddingWeights, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance];
Assodata = Association@Thread[embeddingWeights -> Range[Length@embeddingWeights]];
ReplaceiablePhone = Table[phoneid[[x]] -> phoneid[[Assodata[nearstData[embeddingWeights[[phoneid[[x, 1]] + 1]], 2][[2]]]]], {x, Length@phoneid}];
confusionMatrixData = #[[1, 2]] -> #[[2, 2]] & /@ ReplaceiablePhone;
phone = Union@confusionMatrixData[[All, 1]];
features = DimensionReduce[embeddingWeights, 2, Method -> "TSNE"];
classify = GroupBy[Thread[features -> phoneid[[All, 2]]], Last -> First];
ListPlot[Values[classify], PlotLegends -> PointLegend[97, Keys@classify, LegendMarkerSize -> 15]]
```

[image]

ehh....not well.Still have misclassified data.But we can make it better.

```
ListPlot[List /@ Median /@ Values[classify], PlotLegends -> PointLegend[97, Keys@classify, LegendMarkerSize -> 15]]
(*get the center of same phone,use median to avoid extreme value*)
```

[image]

```
phoneidClassify = GroupBy[#[[1]] + 1 -> #[[2]] & /@ phoneid, Last -> First]
```

> <|"aa" -> {1, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 18, 19, 21, 27, 31, 32, 34, 35, 37,
>       45, 47, 49, 50, 51, 55, 57, 59, 60, 62, 63, 67, 69, 70, 73, 74, 
>      75, 78, 91, 95, 98, 100, 105, 110, 111, 114, 116, 121, 133, 135, 
>      137, 140, 145, 146, 154, 159, 161, 164, 167, 172, 174, 176, 177, 
>      180}, "ae" -> {2, 3, 6, 9, 11, 15, 17, 20, 25, 26, 28, 41, 42, 43, 
>      52, 53, 54, 56, 66, 68, 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 89, 90, 93, 97, 102, 
>      104, 106, 107, 108, 109, 113, 117, 120, 123, 127, 128, 129, 131, 
>      132, 138, 139, 142, 144, 147, 148, 152, 153, 155, 156, 157, 162, 
>      165, 166, 173, 178}, 
>    "ah" -> {7, 14, 16, 22, 23, 24, 29, 30, 33, 36, 38, 39, 40, 44, 46, 
>      48, 58, 61, 64, 65, 71, 72, 76, 77, 79, 80, 84, 87, 88, 92, 94, 96,
>       99, 101, 103, 112, 115, 118, 119, 122, 124, 125, 126, 130, 134, 
>      136, 141, 143, 149, 150, 151, 158, 160, 163, 168, 169, 170, 171, 
>      175, 179}|>

It means the first,4-th, 5-th, 8-th adn so on phone is belong to "aa",the second,third 6-th and so on is belong to "ae"...etc...

Then we use the median vector of the same phone to replace the original vector.

```
Do[embeddingWeights[[phoneidClassify[i]]] = Median@embeddingWeights[[phoneidClassify[i]]], {i, Keys[phoneidClassify]}];
```

Now,all the nearest of the phone is the same phone.

So we are train the second net.
Same net structure as before.

```
net2 = NetInitialize@NetGraph[{EmbeddingLayer[32, "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Class", Range[0, INPUTNOTE]}]], CatenateLayer[], 64, Ramp, 64, Ramp, 43},{NetPort["EmbeddingLayerInput"] -> 1 -> 2, NetPort["Input2"] -> 2, 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7}, "Input2" -> 12];
net2[[1]] = NetReplacePart[net2[[1]], {"Weights" -> embeddingWeights}];
```

But now ,the most import is,we want the weights of embedding layer change slowly because it has no misclassified data.So the tip is use `LearningRateMultipliers`.

```
{net2, LossEvolutionPlot2} = NetTrain[net2,generator,MeanSquaredLossLayer[], 
  {"TrainedNet", "LossEvolutionPlot"}, BatchSize -> 64, MaxTrainingRounds -> Round[Length[data]/64*100], 
  LearningRateMultipliers -> {1 -> 0.0006, _ -> 1}];
```

[image]

Now we plot the confusion matrix

```
embeddingWeights = NetExtract[net2[[1]], "Weights"];
phoneid = Import["https://wolfr.am/m6DNA4FN", "Table"];
nearstData = Nearest[embeddingWeights, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance];
Assodata = Association@Thread[embeddingWeights -> Range[Length@embeddingWeights]];
ReplaceiablePhone = Table[phoneid[[x]] -> phoneid[[Assodata[nearstData[embeddingWeights[[phoneid[[x, 1]] + 1]], 2][[2]]]]], {x, Length@phoneid}];
confusionMatrixData = #[[1, 2]] -> #[[2, 2]] & /@ ReplaceiablePhone;
phone = Union@confusionMatrixData[[All, 1]];

m = Normal@SparseArray@Normal@Counts[{#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ (confusionMatrixData /. Thread[phone -> Range[Length@phone]])];
t = Transpose@Map[Flatten, {#, Reverse@Transpose@#} &[Table[Range[1, 2 # - 1, 2], {#}]] &[Length@m]]/2;
p = MatrixPlot[m, Epilog -> Text @@@ Transpose[{Catenate@m, t}], FrameTicks -> {Transpose@{Range[Length@phone], phone}, Transpose@{Range[Length@phone], Total[m, {1}]}, Transpose@{Range[Length@phone], Total[m, {2}]},Transpose@{Range[Length@phone], phone}}, ImageSize -> 150];
Column[{Row[{Rotate["phone", 90 Degree], p}, Alignment -> Center], "Nearest phone"}, Alignment -> Center]

features = DimensionReduce[embeddingWeights, 2, Method -> "TSNE"];
classify = GroupBy[Thread[features -> phoneid[[All, 2]]], Last -> First];
ListPlot[Values[classify], PlotLegends -> PointLegend[97, Keys@classify, LegendMarkerSize -> 15]]
```

[image]

even on full phone

[image]

We see all the phone are classified correctly.
And it really has clusters.

---------------------------------------**Update 2018/8/15**---------------------------------------

I find if there is some aliasing, it comes from the ***model's structure*** and database(***children's audio books corpus***). It's full with *emotion* that difficult to deal with it.

If pre-trained the model and limit the learning rate, it can not represent the vector of phoneme precisely.

The better way is ***add additional information*** to the net's output, we can get more accurate vector to represent the vector of phoneme.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. And thanks for sharing the solutions.

Comment: Thank you indeed!!! Giving me so many idea

Answer (score 2):

I do not fully understand what you want to do with the two inputs, but here are two examples using `NetPairEmbeddingOperator` to find an embedding so that the similar objects are close in the embedding. I will use data similar to yours in the first example and some new data in the second example.

### Example 1

I use your data but increase the dimension of the data

```
data = Rule @@@ 
   Transpose[{Flatten[{RandomReal[1, {300, 50}] + 0, 
       RandomReal[0.6, {300, 50}] + 0.4, 
       RandomReal[0.2, {300, 50}] + 0.8}, 1], 
     Flatten[{Table[1, {300}], Table[2, {300}], Table[3, 300]}]}];

generator = 
      Function[Table[
        With[{sp = RandomSample[data, 2]}, 
         sp[[All, 1]] -> Not[Equal @@ sp[[All, 2]]]], {#BatchSize}]];
```

We first define the embedding network

```
embnet = NetChain[{
   LinearLayer[100], Ramp, LinearLayer[2]},
  "Input" -> {50}];
```

Then construct a loss network to measure the performance of the embedding network using `NetPairEmbeddingOperator`

```
net = NetPairEmbeddingOperator[embnet];
```

Train this network, and extract the trained embedding network

```
trained = NetTrain[net, generator];
embnetTrained = NetExtract[trained, "Net"];
```

We can generate the embedded values of the original data, and we see that the three classes has been clearly separated.

```
color = {Blue, Green, Red};
Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], color[[#[[2]]]], Point[embnetTrained[#[[1]]]]} & /@
   data, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

### Example 2

In this example, I'm trying to train an embedding network to separate data generated from three different Gaussian distributions.

```
data1 = With[{μ = 0.5, σ = 0.4}, 
   Table[Table[
      Exp[-((x - μ)^2./(2. σ^2))] + 
       0.4 RandomReal[], {x, -1, 1, 0.01}] -> 1, {100}]];
data2 = With[{μ = 0., σ = 0.4}, 
   Table[Table[
      Exp[-((x - μ)^2./(2. σ^2))] + 
       0.4 RandomReal[], {x, -1, 1, 0.01}] -> 2, {100}]];
data3 = With[{μ = -0.5, σ = 0.4}, 
   Table[Table[
      Exp[-((x - μ)^2./(2. σ^2))] + 
       0.4 RandomReal[], {x, -1, 1, 0.01}] -> 3, {100}]];


data = RandomSample[Chop@Join[data1, data2, data3]];

ListPlot[data[[All, 1]], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[data[[All, 2]]]]]
```

[image]

We again define an embedding network and a loss network

```
generator = 
  Function[Table[
    With[{sp = RandomSample[data, 2]}, 
     sp[[All, 1]] -> (! Equal @@ sp[[All, 2]])], {#BatchSize}]];
embnet = NetChain[{LinearLayer[100], Ramp, 10, Ramp, LinearLayer[2]}, 
  "Input" -> {201}]
net = NetPairEmbeddingOperator[embnet]
```

Train the loss network and extract the trained embedding network

```
trained = NetTrain[net, generator, MaxTrainingRounds -> 100]
embnetTrained = NetExtract[trained, "Net"];

Legended[Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], color[[#[[2]]]], 
     Point[embnetTrained[#[[1]]]]} & /@ data, AspectRatio -> 1], 
 PointLegend[color, {1, 2, 3}]]
```

We again see a clean separation for the three different groups[image]

Comment: Thank you very much..But because I describe the question not clear before,I add more information. In your answer,I don't think use NetChain[...,Ramp,...] to replace `EmbeddingLayer` is a good idea.Because every row of weights of `EmbeddingLayer` is a 32-dims feature that can describe the phone.